# How can I stop the iOS Media Player framework logging on each query?

Tags: ios

I'm using the iOS `MediaPlayer.framework` to retrieve data about the user's iTunes library. I do this using the following code:

```
MPMediaQuery * allSongsQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
NSArray * songsData = [allSongsQuery items];
//Iterate over songsData and fetch values for various keys, including title/album/artist
```

None of my code makes any calls to `NSLog`, however I'm seeing that the Media Player framework is logging a lot during this query:

```
{MediaLibrary} Database validation succeeded
{MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
{MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
{MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
{MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
{MediaLibrary} Rolling back transaction.
... (continues on another 200 times)
```

Whilst this doesn't really affect the execution of my application, it is *incredibly* annoying when debugging. Is there any way of stopping the Media Player framework from logging?